# Select most viewed item by tag name with mysql

Tags: mysql, select, union

I have 2 tables: `items` and `items_purchased`. The `tag` name and other descriptive information is in the `items` table and the # of purchases for each item is saved in the `items_purchased` table. The tables are `JOIN`ed on item_id.

Here's my query so far:

```
(select *, sum(purchaseyesno) as tots from items join items_purchased on items.item_id=items_purchased.item_id where tag = 'History' and deleted!=1 and pub_priv!=1    order by tots desc limit 1)
UNION ALL
(select *, sum(purchaseyesno) as tots from items join items_purchased on items.item_id=items_purchased.item_id where tag = 'Medicine' and deleted!=1 and pub_priv!=1  order by tots desc limit 1)
UNION ALL
(select *, sum(purchaseyesno) as tots from items join items_purchased on items.item_id=items_purchased.item_id where tag = 'Biology' and deleted!=1 and pub_priv!=1  order by tots desc limit 1)
//... more tags (20 in all) would follow
```

The problem is that items with certain tags haven't been purchased yet so the query throws an error of `Column "item_id" cannot be null`.

here's the sample tables:

```
            items              |     items_purchased   |   
  item_id   tag      title     | item_id  purchaseyesno|
    1     Biology  DNA is cool |    1         1        | 
    2     Medicine  Doctors    |    2         1        |  
    3      Law    Laws are cool|    4         1        |    
    4     Biology DNA NOT cool |    1         1        |
```

Sample results:

```
item_id   tag       title      tots
  1      Biology   DNA is cool  2
  2      Medicine  Doctors      1
  3       Law   Laws are cool   0
```

2 questions:

1. How can I exclude one of these `SELECT` statements if the results of it will be `NULL`?
2. Is there a better way to do this query rather than 20 select statements joined by 19 `UNION ALL`s?

Comment: dont you have a master table of tags?

Comment: I could but don't have one yet, i'm still thinking of how to build my schema

Comment: Using the aggregate function `SUM` without `GROUP BY` implicitly groups on all rows; selecting `*` results in an indeterminate record being retrieved (see [the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html) for more information)... can you show sample table data and sample desired results?

Comment: yes, i'll add sample table data/results now...

Comment: Why does Biology have tots=2?  Why isn't the purchase of `item_id=4` appearing in your resultset?

Comment: @eggyal because item_id=4 was purchased fewer times than item_id=1 and both have the Biology tag so item_id=1 gets selected.

Comment: What if they had both been purchased an equal number of times?

Comment: still would like to pick only 1, it wouldn't matter which one in that case

Comment: @eggyal, any thoughts on picking just one for each tag?

Comment: @timpeterson: See [my revised answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11205793/623041).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply want to group your results—nothing more complicated than that (no `UNION` in sight!):

```
SELECT   items.*, SUM(purchaseyesno) AS tots
FROM     items JOIN items_purchased USING (item_id)
GROUP BY item_id
```

---

**UPDATE**

Following the comments beneath and the update to the OP's question, it's clear that the problem is more complicated than first thought: it is, in fact, a special case of the [group-wise maximum](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html) problem.

However, the column over which the maximum must be taken is itself the result of another group-wise aggregation (the summation of `purchaseyesno`).

Therefore, one's query becomes rather inelegant with subqueries:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT   items.*, IFNULL(SUM(purchaseyesno),0) AS tots
  FROM     items LEFT JOIN items_purchased ON folder_id = item_id
  GROUP BY item_id
) AS t NATURAL JOIN (
  SELECT tag, MAX(tots) AS tots
  FROM (
    SELECT   items.*, IFNULL(SUM(purchaseyesno),0) AS tots
    FROM     items LEFT JOIN items_purchased ON folder_id = item_id
    GROUP BY item_id
  ) AS u
  GROUP BY tag
) AS v
GROUP BY tag
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ad7f5/2).

What's happening here is that (using an [outer join](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html) to include records such as `Law` that have no references in the `items_purchased` table), we take the sum of purchases for each item (materialised table `u`) and then determine the maximum number of purchases for items with the same tag name.

We then join the result (materialised table `v`) back with the first table (`u`, materialised again as table `t`) on both tag name and number of purchases.

Finally we group the results again by `tag` to ensure that, if multiple items having the same tag have the same number of maximal purchases, only one of them is returned indeterminately.

Comment: It wont be a simple join, since you will get item3 too

Comment: @SashiKant: The OP's desired resultset omits `item_id=3`, so I have used an inner join rather than an outer one.  This achieves exactly what was desired.  See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/92b5c/1).

Comment: @eggyal thanks for your answer, i oversimplified my question for the point of demonstration. Can you tell me how your query would look it the items table `item_id` was actually called `folder_id` but the items_purchased is still called `item_id`?

Comment: @timpeterson: In that case, just go back to using `ON` instead of `USING`: `... FROM items JOIN items_purchased ON items.folder_id = items_purchased.item_id ...`

Comment: hmm, the result of your query almost looks right, there are a few result rows with the same tag name. Would I use a `LIMIT 1` somewhere to restrict to just the ones with the highest `tots`?

Comment: @timpeterson: The sample resultset in your question has multiple records with the same tag name (e.g. `Biology`, which exists with different `item_id`).  If that's not what you're after, please update your question.

Comment: oh yeah, sorry about that, i'm getting confused. I'll change my answer to eliminate that 2nd Biology result row and to add the Law result row with `tots`=0.

Comment: @timpeterson: To include `Law`, just turn my `JOIN` into `LEFT JOIN` (learn about [SQL joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)).  To omit the repeated `Biology`, you'll need to explain how you're deciding to overlook that record in the `items_purchased` table as mentioned in [my comment above](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11205424/select-most-viewed-item-by-tag-name-with-mysql/11205793#comment14711649_11205424).

Comment: @eggyal your updated answer is really great work! thanks for the explanation too, one last thing is to include the tag even if `tots=0`, currently `Law` in my sample results is being excluded using this query

Comment: @eggyal nevermind, i figured this last question out, I just need to group by `folder_id`, rather than `item_id`, thanks again for all your help!!

Answer (score 0):

Create a master table tags , and store its id in the table it is used as name.
Then the below query will be the solution of your problem..

```
select *, sum(purchaseyesno) as tots 
from items left join 
items_purchased ip on (items.item_id=items_purchased.item_id)
inner join tag_table on (tag_table.id=tagId)
where  deleted!=1 and pub_priv!=1 and not items.item_id is null group by tagID
```

Comment: -@sashi  thanks! i'm generating sample table data/results but will do that in the next few minutes..

Comment: This query still returns indeterminate results, as mentioned in [my comment above](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11205424/select-most-viewed-item-by-tag-name-with-mysql#comment14710700_11205424).

Comment: @eggyal: Please check my query properly, coz I have used group by

Comment: Whilst your use of `GROUP BY` means that the results are no longer implicitly grouped on all rows, selecting ungrouped columns will be indeterminate (unless all records are the same on that column).

Comment: Check my where clause there is a clause "and not items.item_id is null" bcoz I have left join it.

Comment: @SashiKant: That has no bearing on my point; and in any event `items` is the full table in your outer join, so that `WHERE` criterion doesn't achieve what you appear to suggest (whereas a similar criterion on `items_purchased.item_id` would, but then why use an outer join at all?).

Comment: @SashiKant, Using your query I'm still getting some of the tags represented more than once in the results. Is there any way to modify your query such that only 1 per tag is selected (the most purchased one)?

Comment: @timpeterson: HAve changed my query, kindly check

Comment: @SashiKant, thanks for checking, yes this works perfectly! For now i may go with eggyal's since then I won't have to refactor other queries to account for this `tags` table but I will definitely keep your query in mind as I move forward, thanks again!